# If one test fails, I need to skip the rest of the tests in that particular suite - testng

Tags: testng

I have a requirement that in my testng.xml suite as below.

The below code displays how my current xml file is present.

```
<suite> <test1> < class/> </test1> <test2> <class1/> <class2/> <class3/> </test2> </suite>
```

If test 1 fails, I need to skip test 2. But here the constraint is I can not edit the classes under test 2 to specify any kind of annotation, so all the modifications I can only do in testng.xml . Please suggest any kind of dependency I can add in testng.xml for this kind of scenario

I have researched about dependency on groups, dependency on methods but all they show is through annotation methods for which i need to edit classes but I can not do it here.

Comment: here is the sample code <suite>
         <test1>
           < class/>
         </test1>
        
         <test2>
            <class1/>
            <class2/>
            <class3/>
         </test2>
        </suite>

Answer (score 0):

Use listeners `IMethodInterceptor`. Intercept each method store its result after test run. If it is pass then continue else skip all further test executions.